# Commit .testsettings association to source control in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, version-control

I have committed the .testsettings file and .vsmdi file to source control; however, when other members of my team get latest then the .testsettings file association that is applied to the solution on my machine doesn't seem to have been maintained (they have to select the appropriate .testsettings file again for tests to work properly).

It appears that if I delete the .suo file then the association is lost on my local machine as well. I thought checking in .suo files was generally discouraged. Do you really have to check in the .suo file too in order to save the .testsettings file association? Or is there some trick to set this by editing the .sln file manually?